# Blazor Scoped DI gets null for the subscribed Action

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have got two Blazor pages that I want to communicate.
I have the Service registered as :

```
services.AddScoped<IUserStateService, UserStateService>();
```

In IUserStateService is as below :

```
   public interface IUserStateService
    {
        event Action? OnVerificationReportListChange;
        Task ReloadVerificationReportListAsync();
    }
```

And the UserStateService is defined as :

```
public class UserStateService : BaseService, IUserStateService, IDisposable
{
public event Action? OnVerificationReportListChange;
public async Task ReloadVerificationReportListAsync()
        {
            if (OnVerificationReportListChange != null)
            {
                OnVerificationReportListChange.Invoke();
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

Page where it the Action is subscribed is :

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            UserStateService.OnVerificationReportListChange += OnReportIsVerified;
        }
 protected void OnReportIsVerified()
        {
            Task.FromResult(RefreshScreen());
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
```

And finally, where the service is called to invoke the Action is :

```
protected async Task VerifyReport()
        {
            
                await UserStateService.ReloadVerificationReportListAsync();
            
        }
```

Can you please suggest why I am getting **OnVerificationReportListChange** be null while calling **ReloadVerificationReportListAsync** and therefore the subscribed method is never being invoked ?

**Update**

I have changed the service registration from **Scoped** to **Singleton** and now it works. So my question is, isn't **Scoped** be **Singleton** within a user session ?

**Update**

Please note I have in _Host - I have :

```
<component type="typeof(App)" **render-mode="Server"** />
```

Which suppose to create one instance of the service for each user - however it looks like its not : https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/comparing-dependency-scopes/

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. If you want further assistment, please upload a complete working repro of your app to Github, so I can inspect it. See this answer, compare it to yours, play with it and try to find out the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042629/6152891

Comment: Thanks @enet. Do you think anything to do with the async - await ? Please note - the comm I am trying to do on two different page open on two browser tab - however on same user scope. Do you think this can be a potential issue ? I have the code in quite a large project. I will try to split it up to share.

Comment: If you're using `_Host,` then your app is Blazor Server App, right ? But you chose the blazor webassembly tag. Please clarify. Note: a Blazor SPA contains only a single page within which the complete app is displayed: Single Page Application (SPA), right. So what you're trying to do, is to communicate between two instances of the app running on the same browser. This is not a communication between two pages, but between two  instances of the app. If you use a Singleton then each instance gets the same instance of your service. This can be problemtic, especially in the sphere of security.

Comment: To allow communication between two instances of the same app, whether on the same browser or a different browser, on the same PC or different PC, you should use SignalR. Now, it is not entirely clear what you're trying to do, so no definite answer here.